# Member of linear space spanned by trigonometric series

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, trigonometry

In my last question I asked about finite linear combination. I know that it isn't true that $\pi - x^2$ is a linear combination but maybe $\pi - x^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_i b_i$, where $b_i$ is i-th element of $\lbrace 1, \cos x, \sin x, \cos 2x, \sin 2x, \cos 3x, \sin 3x, \ldots \rbrace$ and $a_i$ are real numbers?
If it's true how to prove it?

Edit : Assume that $x \in [0, \pi]$.

Comment: It's not the same.

Comment: What does $Lin$ mean, if not (finite) linear combinations of ...?

Comment: You should specify the domain of your functions. If the domain consists of numbers ${0,1,2}$, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @Normal, Is it ok now?

Comment: You still haven't said if you want equality for all $x$ for just on some interval.

Comment: Let $x \in [0, \pi]$.

Comment: @YagnaPatel: It's not even a "possible duplicate", and you should read questions more attentively before triggering a close process: here the OP asks about a *series* (i.e. infinitely many terms), in the other question about a *sum* (i.e. finitely many terms).

Comment: @AlexM. Sorry about that. But at first glance (before all the edits) it looked very similar to OP's previous question.

Comment: Do you understand and are you allowed to use [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)? You could extend your function $\pi-x^2$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ then use Fourier analysis to find the coefficients $a_i$ for your series. So the answer is Yes, it is possible. Fourier analysis proves it. If you can't use that, you could find the $a_i$ and show that the series converges as you want.

Comment: No, I'm not allowed to use Fourier series :/

Comment: Are you allowed to use Fourier Series theory if you re-invent all of it in your answer?

Comment: I think yes, but can it we do it easier than using Fourier series theory?